# Indenting not working (MikTeX/XeLaTeX)

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to use LaTeX, fresh install of MiKTeX and TeXworks, and so far looking this issue up I get:

- "Use double spaces after paragraphs", which I'm already doing.
- `\parindent` parameter must be set, which I put

  ```
  \setlength{\parindent}{24 pt}
  ```

in the preamble, and still there's no indent.

- Put

  ```
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  ```

in the preamble, and no indents.

- Use `\indent`  (which doesn't do anything either)

I've been using [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_indent_and_break) as a reference. I've been at this for a while, and my document has it's images and other formatting, but one of the only things that's making it incomplete is the lack of indents.

If it helps, my preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % different font colors.
\usepackage{fontspec}% use system installed fonts.
\usepackage{graphicx}% import images.
\usepackage{multirow}% tables with nonuniform row:columns.
\usepackage{multicol}% dual column for text body.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}%
% suppress section numbering
% this is so bookmarks appear from hyperref
% and still have no numbering.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
\makeatother
% for indenting
% default is 15pt.
\setlength{\parindent}{24 pt}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{indentfirst}  
\setlength{\parindent}{24 pt}  

\begin{document}
\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}
\color{white}
\raggedright

\begin{multicols}{2}

    first filler paragraph filler   filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler.


    second filler paragraph filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler.


    third filler paragraph filler filler    filler  filler  filler  filler  filler  filler.


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Looks like [image: compiled on my end]

Comment: If you are asking about indenting a paragraph it would be more helpful to show an example of a paragraph rather than examples setting graphicspath etc. You are using `indentfirst` so all paragraphs should normally be indented (except in minipages and parboxes where it defaults to 0) if you are not seeing that, make a small _complete_ example that shows the problem.

Comment: Oh note that indent is the horizontal  space at the start of teh first line. Your refer to "double space after paragraph" the vertical space beyween paragraphs is `\parskip` not `\parindent`.

Comment: Welcome, can you please collect all the snippets in a compilable example? That way, we see the same output you see.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could clip out as a good example. There's a lot of images in the document, and it's currently 9 pages. Would extra text before and after the sample paragraph help?

Comment: @amph It's not the text that's important, it's having a short example that reproduces the problem: see details on creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Very good example. http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=86015#p86015

Comment: `\raggedright` sets the parindent to 0. see why we need an example, your original question did not mention that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ragged2e` package: it allows for some hyphenation, and defines a `\RaggedRightParindent` length (0pt by default):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRightParindent = 24 pt

\begin{document}

\RaggedRight
\begin{multicols}{2}

   First filler paragraph filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

    Second filler paragraph filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

   Third filler paragraph filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]